# I am in need of a Python program to merge/rename attribute values together within a single column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I need to transform the dataset into a numerical one.

I can use the function from the pandas package get_dummies() to transform all your categorical attributes into asymmetric binary ones. Before doing so, I should first merge/rename attribute values together to have fewer asymmetric binary attributes. My dataset consists of 3700 rows and 12 columns with an attribute native.country and it has various values like United States, Mexico, China, Canada, Germany, Haiti, Italy and many more. I am trying to group United States and other countries separately within a single column in Python. For eg:native country: United-States, other (all the other countries).

I tried using groupby, renaming in pandas expecting to group countries separately but I am not getting it. Getting Keyerror and False error.

I am doing the following in the code:

```
    adult_train=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/jayan/Downloads/adult_train.csv")
    print(adult_train)
    adult_df=pd.DataFrame(adult_train)
    print('original data')
    print(adult_df)
    adult_df1.drop(adult_df1.loc[adult_df1['occupation'] == '?'].index, 
    inplace=True, axis=1)
    print('Data after removing missing values in the original data')
    print(adult_df1)
    adult_df2=adult_df1.drop(['fnlwgt','education','relationship'],axis=1)
    print("After dropping three attributes in the Training set")
    print(adult_df2)
```

Now I need to transform the native.country attribute in adult_train dataset into above said method. I am using the below code:

```py
    adult_df2=pd.DataFrame(adult_df1)if('native.country'!='United-States'):
    f1= lambda x: len(x.split())
    other=adult_df2['native.country'!='United-States'].apply(f1)
    print(other)
```

```
KeyError: True The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [198], in <cell line: 17>() 17 if('native.country'!='United-States'): 18 f1= lambda x: len(x.split()) ---> 19 other=adult_df2['native.country'!='United-States'].apply(f1) 20 print(other)
```

Comment: You can provide what you've tried by attaching your code, the errors, the result, and where the result doesn't meet your expectation.

Comment: Please edit your question attaching your comment above instead put it in the comment.

Comment: You can display code properly by starting each line of code with 4 spaces...